# rqrcode returning an entirely white PNG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, qr-code

The following method

```
require 'rqrcode'
[...]
@items.each do |item|
  @qr_string = @qr_string + item.codes.first.code.to_s + '\t' + item.value.to_s + '\t' + rand(1..4).to_s + '\r'
end
@qr_string = @qr_string + '\r'
qrcode = RQRCode::QRCode.new(@qr_string.to_s)
png = qrcode.as_png(
  bit_depth: 1,
  border_modules: 4,
  color_mode: ChunkyPNG::COLOR_GRAYSCALE,
  color: 'black',
  file: nil,
  fill: 'white',
  module_px_size: 6,
  resize_exactly_to: false,
  resize_gte_to: false,
  size: 120
)
```

If the console is queried

```
> qrcode
=> #<RQRCode::QRCode:0x00007feb44d9d370 @qrcode=QRCodeCore: @data='H\t1\t4\r2042700000000\t8.9\t2\r2017290000000\t5.99\t2\r2040890000000\t18.9\t3\r2230030000000\t2.8\t1\r2012910000000\t17.99\t3\r2229170000000\t4.8\t1\r2013820000000\t5.2\t4\r2081670000000\t8.29\t1\r2012490000000\t7.99\t3\r2007640000000\t16.49\t4\r2008390000000\t0.01\t2\r2008400000000\t0.01\t2\r2008020000000\t0.01\t4\r2007660000000\t0.01\t3\r2008040000000\t0.01\t1\r2008420000000\t0.01\t3\r2009010000000\t0.01\t1\r2009020000000\t8.99\t4\r2002020000000\t11.29\t3\r2007700000000\t4.49\t2\r\r', @error_correct_level=2, @version=24, @module_count=113>
```

but the result returned for object `png`

```
> png
=> <ChunkyPNG::Image 120x120 [
    [#ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff #ffffffff]
```

Is entirely white.  Yet if I use the [the gem's example](https://github.com/whomwah/rqrcode#as-png),

```
qrcode = RQRCode::QRCode.new("http://github.com/")
=> #<RQRCode::QRCode:0x00007feb424b9328 @qrcode=QRCodeCore: @data='http://github.com/', @error_correct_level=2, @version=3, @module_count=29>
```

the qrcode is being generated properly.

Since the `png` method is identical, what is wrong with the `qrcode` output?

Through isolation I have determined that the final `\r`is the nuisance

```
   @qr_string = @qr_string + item.codes.first.code.to_s + '\t' + item.value.to_s + '\t' + rand(1..4).to_s + '\r'
```

when cast as:

```
   @qr_string = @qr_string + item.codes.first.code.to_s + '\t' + item.value.to_s + '\t' + rand(1..4).to_s
```

a code is rendered.  This is unexpected

`rqrcode` gem version 1.1.2

Comment: did you try to save it as an image? It should work as expected `IO.binwrite("/tmp/qr-code.png", png.to_s)`

Comment: the image appears blank (it is all white as per the result of the method).  The problem is elsewhere.  I have now determined by isolating the elements that it is the final element which is throwing the entire rendering off.

Comment: It is as if there were one too many elements in the concatenation.

Comment: Could it be the carriage returns?

Comment: I initially assumed it was that but I have a different set-up where the carriage return is in there and renders - however, only if I pluck a tabulation out of the string beforehand...